# How do I create parameters in a Joomla module depending on another parameter / number?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla4

I'm trying to create a joomla **module for typical css cards** but I want to make to **card number dependent on a number input from the user**. *For example the user wants 5 cards so in the parameter field "number of cards" he puts '5'.*

Now he has to choose the text and logo for each card he wants, but how **can I 'spawn' paramter values during runtime?**

I could just put a set number of cards in and define the corresponding paramters in the modules xml but is there a way to do it like I want to?

Would greatly appreciate the help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are likely to receive better support for your Joomla questions if you post them on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/32186/how-do-i-create-parameters-in-a-joomla-module-depending-on-another-parameter-n